# How can user account will automatic suspend after specific time in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In my website i have more than 50 user.

At the time of creating user account, there should be some option like (date in month) that i can select and after completion of month that account will automatically suspend.

Thanks In Advance.

i am expecting that let my problem be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a membership plugin for this https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-membership/.

Another option is to develop custom code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own code, or use some plugin for that:

Example plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

Example hooks to use when checking user expiration date (in functions.php of your plugin):
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/is_protected_endpoint/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_bad_session_token/